# Android alarm with notification running any date when I change date

Tags: android, alarmmanager, notificationmanager

I am using `AlarmManager` and `NotificationManager` with `BroadcastReceiver`.
When I set an alarm with a specific date, it is working the first time. However, when I modify the date and click the confirm button, the alarm is working any date
immediately. I want to set the alarm interval day after expired date with fixed time.
What is the problem with it? I don't understand at the moment.

```
confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //set alarm with expiration date                
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    setOneTimeAlarm();
    Toast.makeText(fridgeDetails.this, "Alarm automatic set", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}

public void setOneTimeAlarm() {
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 49);
    c.set(expiredYear, expiredMonth, expiredDay);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(fridgeDetails.this, AlarmService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        fridgeDetails.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
});
```

AlarmService.java

```
public class AlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver{
    NotificationManager nm;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence from = "Check your fridge";
        CharSequence message = "It's time to eat!";
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(), 0);
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Keep Fridge", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
        notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 
        nm.notify(1, notif);
    }   
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem entirely, but it seems to me that using FLAG_ONE_SHOT is suboptimal in this case, as it will only allow one callback from the AlarmManager. Try using 0 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the property instead of FLAG_ONE_SHOT. This is for single alarm event not for the repeat. try this

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        fridgeDetails.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

see more detail about from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

**Edit:**

As you do for notification with PendingIntent

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,new Intent(), 0);
```

In this you pass the empty object of Intent you need to pass the class name for that when you click on notification which Activity will be launch like in Alarm set time you do

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(fridgeDetails.this, AlarmService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        fridgeDetails.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

now just pass the Acitivity name in the intent like suppose you want to launch your home activity and activity name like "homeactivity"

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,new Intent(context,HomeActivity.class), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! and I have question one more, if I click notification, it does not open existed application. How can I open when I click notification icon?

Comment: After that, how can I call contentIntent ?